# snapsvg - Move path to cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have a complex SVG with multiple paths. I'm trying to the change the path data (d) of the paths to match the position of the cursor so when the user mouseover the svg, they move toward the pointer.

What seem like a simple animation feels more like nightmare considering I'm not sure about my approach and choice of tools.

Here is my SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="graph" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                 viewBox="0 0 222 246.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 222 246.6;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:#52B3F5;}
                .st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:#8FDAFF;}
                .st2{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:#0468FF;}
                .st3{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#0468FF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                .st4{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#8FDAFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#52B3F5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            </style>
            <g>
                <defs>
                    <rect id="SVGID_1_" width="222" height="246.6"/>
                </defs>
                <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
                </clipPath>
                <path class="st0" d="M222,233.8c0,3.2-2.6,5.8-5.8,5.8c-3.2,0-5.8-2.6-5.8-5.8c0-3.2,2.6-5.8,5.8-5.8
                    C219.4,228,222,230.6,222,233.8"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M105.2,150c0,2.1-1.7,3.7-3.7,3.7c-2.1,0-3.7-1.7-3.7-3.7c0-2.1,1.7-3.7,3.7-3.7
                    C103.5,146.2,105.2,147.9,105.2,150"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M34.4,21.1c0,2.5-2,4.5-4.5,4.5s-4.4-2-4.4-4.5c0-2.5,2-4.4,4.4-4.4S34.4,18.6,34.4,21.1"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M110.5,207.1c0,3.3-2.7,5.9-5.9,5.9c-3.3,0-5.9-2.7-5.9-5.9c0-3.3,2.7-5.9,5.9-5.9
                    C107.8,201.2,110.5,203.9,110.5,207.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M128.4,207.1c0,3.9-3.2,7.1-7.1,7.1c-3.9,0-7.1-3.2-7.1-7.1c0-3.9,3.2-7.1,7.1-7.1
                    C125.3,200.1,128.4,203.2,128.4,207.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M22.7,240.8c0,3.2-2.6,5.8-5.8,5.8c-3.2,0-5.8-2.6-5.8-5.8c0-3.2,2.6-5.8,5.8-5.8
                    C20.1,235,22.7,237.6,22.7,240.8"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M9.2,232.7c0,2.6-2.1,4.6-4.6,4.6S0,235.3,0,232.7s2.1-4.6,4.6-4.6S9.2,230.1,9.2,232.7"/>
                <polygon class="st3" points="148.1,105.2 106.2,207.1 120.5,207.1 155.4,122.2    "/>
                <path class="st2" d="M202.5,23.5c0,3.1-2.5,5.7-5.7,5.7s-5.7-2.5-5.7-5.7c0-3.1,2.5-5.7,5.7-5.7S202.5,20.4,202.5,23.5"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M188.7,17.5c0,1.9-1.5,3.4-3.4,3.4c-1.9,0-3.4-1.5-3.4-3.4c0-1.9,1.5-3.4,3.4-3.4
                    C187.2,14.1,188.7,15.6,188.7,17.5"/>
                <polygon class="st3" points="184.4,17.1 106.2,207.1 120.5,207.1 196,23.4 194.2,22.4     "/>
                <polygon class="st4" points="39.4,17 29.5,22.4 27.7,23.3 103.3,207.1 106.3,207.1 117.6,207.1    "/>
                <polygon class="st3" points="118.7,5.6 105.9,5.6 103.2,5.6 5.8,234.2 6.4,234.6 16,241.4     "/>
                <polygon class="st5" points="17.3,242.7 121.4,149.5 111.7,140.8 6.3,234.6 9.2,236.7     "/>
                <polygon class="st5" points="217.3,234.1 111.7,140.8 101.9,149.5 205.8,242.5 206.4,242.1    "/>
                <polygon class="st4" points="217.3,234.1 120.3,5.6 105.8,5.6 206.4,242.1    "/>
                <polygon class="st5" points="181.8,15.6 102,87.3 111.7,96.1 194.2,22.4  "/>
                <polygon class="st5" points="41.7,15.7 29.5,22.4 111.7,96.1 121.6,87.3  "/>
                <path class="st0" d="M46.9,17.7c0,3-2.4,5.3-5.3,5.3c-3,0-5.3-2.4-5.3-5.3c0-3,2.4-5.3,5.3-5.3C44.5,12.3,46.9,14.7,46.9,17.7"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M44.2,20.7c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1s-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1S44.2,19,44.2,20.7"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M31.4,22.3c0,1.5-1.2,2.7-2.7,2.7S26,23.8,26,22.3c0-1.5,1.2-2.7,2.7-2.7S31.4,20.8,31.4,22.3"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M105,5.6c0,2.1-1.7,3.8-3.8,3.8c-2.1,0-3.8-1.7-3.8-3.8c0-2.1,1.7-3.8,3.8-3.8C103.3,1.9,105,3.5,105,5.6"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M124.3,5.6c0,3.1-2.5,5.6-5.6,5.6c-3.1,0-5.6-2.5-5.6-5.6c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.6-5.6C121.8,0,124.3,2.5,124.3,5.6"
                    />
                <path class="st1" d="M123.6,5.6c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1
                    C122.2,2.5,123.6,3.9,123.6,5.6"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M186.2,15.7c0,2.5-2.1,4.6-4.6,4.6s-4.6-2.1-4.6-4.6c0-2.5,2.1-4.6,4.6-4.6S186.2,13.2,186.2,15.7"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M197.8,22.4c0,2.1-1.7,3.8-3.8,3.8c-2.1,0-3.8-1.7-3.8-3.8c0-2.1,1.7-3.8,3.8-3.8
                    C196.1,18.7,197.8,20.3,197.8,22.4"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M199.4,22.4c0,2.9-2.4,5.3-5.3,5.3c-2.9,0-5.3-2.4-5.3-5.3c0-2.9,2.4-5.3,5.3-5.3
                    C197,17.1,199.4,19.5,199.4,22.4"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M111.4,5.6c0,3.1-2.5,5.6-5.6,5.6c-3.1,0-5.6-2.5-5.6-5.6c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.6-5.6C108.9,0,111.4,2.5,111.4,5.6"
                    />
                <path class="st0" d="M142.4,52.6c0,1.1-0.9,2.1-2.1,2.1c-1.1,0-2.1-0.9-2.1-2.1c0-1.1,0.9-2.1,2.1-2.1
                    C141.5,50.5,142.4,51.5,142.4,52.6"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M132.9,61.7c0,1.6-1.3,3-3,3c-1.6,0-3-1.3-3-3c0-1.6,1.3-3,3-3C131.5,58.8,132.9,60.1,132.9,61.7"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M149.1,65.5c0,2-1.7,3.7-3.7,3.7s-3.7-1.7-3.7-3.7c0-2,1.7-3.7,3.7-3.7S149.1,63.4,149.1,65.5"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M140.2,75.1c0,2.9-2.3,5.2-5.2,5.2c-2.9,0-5.2-2.3-5.2-5.2c0-2.9,2.3-5.2,5.2-5.2
                    C137.9,69.9,140.2,72.2,140.2,75.1"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M221,233.8c0,2.1-1.7,3.8-3.8,3.8c-2.1,0-3.8-1.7-3.8-3.8s1.7-3.8,3.8-3.8C219.4,230.1,221,231.7,221,233.8"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M209.5,240.7c0,2.1-1.7,3.8-3.8,3.8c-2.1,0-3.8-1.7-3.8-3.8s1.7-3.8,3.8-3.8
                    C207.8,237,209.5,238.7,209.5,240.7"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M85,52.6c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9C84.2,50.7,85,51.5,85,52.6"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M96.1,62c0,1.5-1.2,2.7-2.7,2.7c-1.5,0-2.7-1.2-2.7-2.7c0-1.5,1.2-2.7,2.7-2.7C94.9,59.3,96.1,60.5,96.1,62"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M9.2,233.7c0,1.6-1.3,2.9-2.9,2.9s-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9S9.2,232.1,9.2,233.7"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M82.7,65.7c0,2.6-2.1,4.7-4.7,4.7c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.7c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7C80.5,61,82.7,63.1,82.7,65.7"
                    />
                <path class="st0" d="M90.1,75.1c0,1-0.8,1.9-1.9,1.9c-1,0-1.9-0.8-1.9-1.9c0-1,0.8-1.9,1.9-1.9C89.3,73.2,90.1,74.1,90.1,75.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M150.4,105.2c0,1.5-1.2,2.7-2.7,2.7c-1.5,0-2.7-1.2-2.7-2.7c0-1.5,1.2-2.7,2.7-2.7
                    C149.2,102.6,150.4,103.8,150.4,105.2"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M159.7,123c0,2.2-1.8,4-4,4c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4c0-2.2,1.8-4,4-4C157.9,119,159.7,120.7,159.7,123"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M159.2,88c0,2.2-1.8,4-4,4c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4c0-2.2,1.8-4,4-4C157.4,83.9,159.2,85.7,159.2,88"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M165.2,105.7c0,1.5-1.2,2.7-2.7,2.7c-1.5,0-2.7-1.2-2.7-2.7c0-1.5,1.2-2.7,2.7-2.7
                    C164,103.1,165.2,104.2,165.2,105.7"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M79.9,104.1c0,2.4-1.9,4.3-4.3,4.3c-2.4,0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.3c0-2.4,1.9-4.3,4.3-4.3
                    C78,99.7,79.9,101.7,79.9,104.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M109.8,207.1c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6
                    C108.2,203.5,109.8,205.2,109.8,207.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M71,86.7c0,1.6-1.3,2.9-2.9,2.9s-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9S71,85.1,71,86.7"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M22.7,240.8c0,2-1.7,3.7-3.7,3.7s-3.7-1.7-3.7-3.7c0-2.1,1.7-3.7,3.7-3.7S22.7,238.7,22.7,240.8"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M123.7,207.1c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5C121.4,202.1,123.7,204.4,123.7,207.1"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M114.3,140.8c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1s-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1S114.3,139.1,114.3,140.8"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M104.6,168c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1
                    C103.2,164.9,104.6,166.3,104.6,168"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M94.7,176.6c0,2.2-1.8,4-4,4c-2.2,0-4-1.8-4-4s1.8-4,4-4C92.9,172.7,94.7,174.4,94.7,176.6"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M121,168c0,0.9,0.7,1.6,1.6,1.6c0.9,0,1.6-0.7,1.6-1.6c0-0.9-0.7-1.6-1.6-1.6C121.7,166.4,121,167.1,121,168"
                    />
                <path class="st0" d="M136,164.1c0,1.3,1,2.3,2.3,2.3c1.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-2.3c0-1.3-1-2.3-2.3-2.3C137,161.8,136,162.8,136,164.1"/>
                <path class="st2" d="M127.5,176.6c0,3.3,2.6,5.9,5.9,5.9c3.3,0,5.9-2.6,5.9-5.9c0-3.3-2.6-5.9-5.9-5.9
                    C130.1,170.7,127.5,173.4,127.5,176.6"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M125.6,150.1c0,2.7-2.2,5-5,5c-2.7,0-5-2.2-5-5c0-2.7,2.2-5,5-5C123.4,145.2,125.6,147.4,125.6,150.1"/>
                <path class="st1" d="M103.9,154.9c0,3.8-3.1,6.9-6.9,6.9c-3.8,0-6.9-3.1-6.9-6.9c0-3.8,3.1-6.9,6.9-6.9
                    C100.8,148,103.9,151.1,103.9,154.9"/>
                <path class="st0" d="M207.3,239.1c0,1.8-1.5,3.3-3.3,3.3s-3.3-1.5-3.3-3.3s1.5-3.3,3.3-3.3S207.3,237.3,207.3,239.1"/>
            </g>
            </svg>
```

And my full, completely failed attempt [can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/fparent/tsu1a7bw/)

I guess the real question would be how to find the "d" endpoint of the mouse cursor so I can assign it to the paths.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to move the whole path around? Or do you want to move individual points in the path around?

Comment: Ideally everything if that's possible

Comment: If you need to support a generalised `<path>` with potential curves and arcs etc, then that is going to be quite a job to get everything working nicely.  Where every point in the path moves towards the pointer. Paths could end up twisting inside out and looking awful.  If you can assume simpler rules, like a path will move as a whole, and only the polygon points move individually, then that would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cx` and `cy` are for circles and ellipses.  And you don't need to modify the `d` attribute for paths either.

All you need to do to move any element is apply a translate transform. Ie:

```
<path ... transform="translate(20, 20)">
```

In Snap you can use the `Element.transform()` function to apply a transform.

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tsu1a7bw/5/) where I move each path towards the pointer a little bit every time you move the pointer.

```
function moveFunc( ev, x, y ) {
    //console.log(ev);
    paths.forEach(function(el) {
       // Convert screen mouse coords to the equivalent point in SVG coords
       var pt = cursorPoint(x, y);
       // Get the "center" of each path by way of its bounding box
       var b = el.getBBox();
       var cx = b.x + b.width/2;
       var cy = b.y + b.height/2;
       // Get the direction vector from the path center to the pointer location
       var dx = pt.x - cx;
       var dy = pt.y - cy;
       // Get the current transform (if any) on the path
       var currentTransform = el.transform().localMatrix;
       // Add the tranlation that moves the paths a little toward the pointer
       currentTransform = currentTransform.translate(dx/20, dy/20);
       el.transform(currentTransform);
    });
}


// Convert a screen space coordinate to an SVG coordinate
function cursorPoint(x, y) {
  var svg = s.node;
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = x;  pt.y = y;
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.  To move the `<polygon>` points, you'll need to get the array of points and then update each point in the array by adding `dx`,`dy`.

You can get the points of a polygon using `el.node.points`.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect solution, exactly what I needed. Cheers mate!!